# Python - If "a" or "b"

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this (simplified):

```
    foo = input("Test")
    if foo is "a" or "b":
        print("Test")
```

This returns Test for everything that the user inputs, while those work and only return when `a` or `b` is given.

```
    foo = input("Test")
    if foo is "a" or foo is "b":
        print("Test")
```

-

```
    foo = input("Test")
    if foo in ("a" or "b"):
        print("Test")
```

Why does the first one not work?

I can only guess that the first one actually checks if `foo == "a"`, but not if `foo == "b"`, and that the `or "b"` part always returns `True` - but why?

Comment: The first line is evaluating `"b"` as `True`.  To see how python evaluates the 'truthiness' of different objects use `bool()`.

Comment: The question is not the same as the linked one. The OP *knows* the answer already, and asks why the alternatives don't work

Comment: To answer you question, the first one does not work because `if foo is "a" or "b"` checks `(foo is "a") or ("b")`.  When the character "b" is evaluated as a boolean is considered True (anything that is not 0 or None is considered True).
So `(foo is "a") or (True) = True`

Comment: @blue_note Martijn's answer in the first linked dupe gives the reason that the 'simplified' version does not work.

Comment: And use `==` for string comparison, `is` is for object identity.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the 3rd does NOT return True - whats the shortest way to check this then? The second one seems very redundant to me. I assume the shortest way is putting `"a"` and `"b"` in a list? the `("a" or "b")` did not work, i thought that brackets would help just like in math